# The meaning of "the spaces" in the sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "the spaces of 77,438 words" mean?

> An Italian doctor named Paolo Mantegazza promoted the
> medicinal and recreational use of the leaves of the coca plant in
> the mid-nineteenth century. He was so enthralled by his discovery
> that he wrote: “I sneered at the poor mortals condemned to live in
> this valley of tears while I, carried on the wings of two leaves of
> coca, went **flying through the spaces of 77,438 words, each more
> splendid than the one before** . . .”

Comment: I'd guess it's a typo or similar for _worlds_.

Comment: Words, worlds, swords, is irrelevant. It tries to describe his drugged state. I guess you would have to take the same journey to find out.

Comment: It's a very specific number of words. It sounds like a word count to me, from the number of words and the fact that he flew through the spaces beteween them on only one dose of coca I suspect that he's referring to something he was reading, or perhaps skimming as he was high at the time.